# Timeout request due request from Firebase to Merriam-Webster

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I execute a request from Firebase to dictionary service Merriam-Webster. Used module "request-promise". In half cases request is successful, and in half cases an error occurs: "RequestError: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 208.185.238.252:443"

If request to Merriam-Webster is performed not from the Firebase, but, for example, from the local computer, then the request works without errors.
Similarly, if request is not made to another service, for example, Facebook or my own script, then an error does not happen.

```
const request = require( "request-promise" );

const url = "https://www.dictionaryapi.com/api/v3/references/learners/json/test?key=" + learnersApiKey;

request( url )
.then( responce => {
    console.log( "responce = " + responce );
    response.status(200).send("yes");
})
.catch( error => {
    console.log( "error = " + error );
    response.status(200).send("no");
});
```

Comment: sounds like an issue with their api that we're probably not going to be able to help much with. maybe take it up with their support if they have it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "execute a request from Firebase".  Do you mean from Cloud Functions?

Comment: @DougStevenson
yes, from Cloud Function.

Comment: Hi, more information would be needed to troubleshoot your issue. Could you open a [support case](https://cloud.google.com/support/) or create an issue in [Google Issue Tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/create-issue-ui)?